# Over Saturated Snapshot in JavaFX

Tags: java, image, javafx, fxml, snapshot

I've been trying to take a snapshot from my media player in JavaFX but it keeps on giving me an over saturated image.

Sample of the over saturated image taken from excited button.
[Sample of the over saturated image taken from excited button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoCT1.jpg)

I'm out of ideas on how to have a normal snapshot.

Any help and suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you in advance. :)

This is my Java code:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@FXML
private MediaView mediaView;
private String filePath;

@FXML 
private Slider seekSlider;

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter filter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Select a File ('.mp4')", "*.mp4");
            fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(filter);
            File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            filePath = file.toURI().toString();

            if(filePath != null){
                Media media = new Media(filePath);
                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
                mediaView.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);



        mediaPlayer.currentTimeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Duration>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Duration> observable, Duration oldValue, Duration newValue) {
           seekSlider.setMin(0.0);
           seekSlider.setValue(0.0);
           seekSlider.setMax(mediaPlayer.getTotalDuration().toSeconds());
           seekSlider.setValue(newValue.toSeconds());
        }       
            });

            seekSlider.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                     mediaPlayer.seek(Duration.seconds(seekSlider.getValue()));
                    }

            });
     mediaPlayer.play();

            }

}
@FXML
private void pauseVideo(ActionEvent event){
     mediaPlayer.pause();
}
 @FXML
private void playVideo(ActionEvent event){
    mediaPlayer.play();
}
 @FXML
private void stopVideo(ActionEvent event){
    mediaPlayer.stop();
}
@FXML
private void exit(ActionEvent event){
    System.exit(0);
}

@FXML
private void excitedCapture(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
   WritableImage img = mediaView.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
   BufferedImage bufImg = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(img, null);
   ImageIO.write(bufImg, "jpg", new File("hi.jpg"));
}
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that oversaturation is the issue here. I think you are just hit by this bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8119048

As a workaround, you can convert your BufferedImage to a type that does not include alpha and write that. I tested it and it works fine for both PNG and JPEG formats.

```
BufferedImage bImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null);
BufferedImage bImage2 = new BufferedImage(bImage.getWidth(), bImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
bImage2.getGraphics().drawImage(bImage, 0, 0, null);
ImageIO.write(bImage2, FILE_TYPE, file);
```

Comment: It's working fine when I'm saving it as PNG file. But I guess theres a bug when you save it on JPEG. :(

Comment: Apply the workarround and you can also save it as a JPEG. See updated answer above and yes there is a problem with JPEGs. That's what the bug report "Wrong colors in JPEG files" is all about.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Btw. The workaround work. :)